# Assigning same NSString multiple times

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Can an NSString be reused like this:

```
NSString *string = @"first value";

NSLog(string);

string = @"second value";

NSLog(string);
```

This works when tested, but is it proper coding?

Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your example is totally fine.  What is your concern about it being 'improper'?

Edit:  Strictly speaking it is probably safer to use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Instead of just logging the string directly.  I don't think that's what you were asking, though.

Comment: My concern is that it's not a NSMutableString. Does reassigning NSString with a different length string corrupt anything in memory?

Comment: @Jim, you're not modifying any strings in your code; just a pointer to a string.

Comment: Then what happens to "first value"? Does it stay in memory or does it get disposed of? Should I release it?

Comment: @Jim, it stays in memory - it's a constant string, so there's nothing you can do about it.  You don't need to release it since you didn't retain it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the string. Instead you are just assigning a different address to the pointer `string`.

and `@"first String"` and `@"second String"` are just constant strings.